# How to initialise an object of a class which requires a dictionary pattern in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class StorageItem {
  String key;
  int? size;
  DateTime? lastModified;
  String? eTag;

  StorageItem({required this.key, this.size, this.lastModified, this.eTag});
}
```

I want to create an object of this class and initialise it. What's the way to do it?

`StorageItem item;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `key` is required, then you at least need:

```
final item = StorageItem(key: 'yourKeyString');
```

Then you can add and pick different number of arguments:

```
final item = StorageItem(key: 'yourKeyString', size: 1337);
final item = StorageItem(key: 'yourKeyString', size: 1337, lastModified: DateTime.now());
final item = StorageItem(key: 'yourKeyString', size: 1337, lastModified: DateTime.now(), eTag: 'yourETagString');
```

Answer (score 1):

Only key is required in this class, you can do it like

```dart
StorageItem item = StorageItem(key: "your key");

StorageItem item2 = StorageItem(key: "your key",eTag: "tag");
```

You can check more about [instance-variables](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#instance-variables)